# simpleJdbcCall calling Pl/SQL procedure -- ORA-22922 nonexistent LOB value

Tags: java, oracle, jdbctemplate, clob

I am getting this SQLException -- ORA-22922 nonexistent LOB value.

My scenario is:

1. I am calling a procedure which takes a array of structs,
2. The struct contains three types, two are date, and one a Clob
3. When I execute the procedure using Spring's simpleJdbcCall setting the null instead of clob the statement gets executed and data gets written to the database.
4. This tells that my simpleJdbcCall is setup correctly.

Here is my code of creating clob, array and struct and executing the simpleJdbCall.

```
  public void insertRecords(List<MyObject> objectList) throws Exception {
    Array array = null;
    Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
    OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwarp(OracleConnection.class);

    Object[] arrObj = new Object[objectList.size()];
    Object[][] structObj = new Object[objectList.size()][3];

    Clob clob = connection.createClob();
    for(int loop = 0; loop < objectList.size(); loop++) {
       clob.setString(objectList.get(loop).getData);

       structObj[loop][0] = objectList.getDate1();
       structObj[loop][1] = objectList.getDate2();
       structObj[loop][2] = clob; //null; 

       arrObj[loop] = oracleConnection.createStruct(structName, structObj[loop]);
     }

     array = oracleConnection.createOracleArray(collectionName, arrObj);

     Map<String, Array> inparam = new HashMap<~>;

     inparam.put(arrayParamString, array);

     //procInsertData is a SimpleJdbcCall
     procInsertData.exexute(inparam);
     clob.free();
  }
```

Comments and solutions plz...

Update: 5 May 2014 (Debug SQL statement logging output):

```
2014-05-05 11:30:18,126 [main] DEBUG  SimpleJdbcCall - JdbcCall call not compiled    before execution - invoking compile
2014-05-05 11:30:18,296 [main] DEBUG  SimpleJdbcCall - Compiled stored procedure. Call string is [{call MY_DB.WRITE(?)}]
2014-05-05 11:30:18,357 [main] DEBUG  SimpleJdbcCall - SqlCall for procedure [write] compiled
2014-05-05 11:30:18,367 [main] DEBUG  SimpleJdbcCall - The following parameters are used for call {call MY_DB.WRITE(?)} with:  {in_my_objects=org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameterValue@7e4034bd}
2014-05-05 11:30:18,367 [main] DEBUG  SimpleJdbcCall - 1: in_my_objects SQL Type 2003 Type Name MY_OBJECT_COLL org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter
2014-05-05 11:30:18,388 [main] DEBUG  StatementCreatorUtils - Overriding type info with runtime info from SqlParameterValue: column index 1, SQL type 2003, type name null
2014-05-05 11:30:18,388 [main] TRACE  StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [oracle.sql.ARRAY@61d6687a], value class [oracle.sql.ARRAY], SQL type 2003
2014-05-05 11:30:18,447 [main] INFO   XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
2014-05-05 11:30:18,623 [main] INFO   SQLErrorCodesFactory - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call MY_DB.WRITE(?)}]; SQL  state [99999]; error code [22922]; ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value
ORA-06512: at "PKG.MY_DB", line 30
ORA-06512: at line 1
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value
ORA-06512: at "PKG.MY_OBJ", line 30
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: I don't think 4. is a valid conclusion for 3. What if Spring just omits the LOB insert parameter which you set to null? `insert into t (a,b) values...` is quite different from `insert into t (a,b,lob) values...`. Did you enable debug logging to see what SQL statements get issues against the data base?

Comment: Thanks @MarcelStör for the input, I have tried testing the procedure on Oracle to insert data and it was working.  Also, in the code above when struct gets created the struct object in db is checked for these input types before its creation.Not sure how can we enable debug loggin at Spring/Java side. any pointers ?

Comment: @MarcelStör added the debug logs

Answer (score 1):

The Clob instance is tied to the 'oracleConnection' that you use to create it and the SimpleJDBCCall uses another connection for the DB call. There are two independent sessions from the DB point of view and that's the reason why the clob does not exist in the session used by SimpleJDBCCall.

The connection that the SimpleJDBCCall uses must be used for the Clob creation.

I have managed to solve a similar problem by implementing SQLData and by extracting the current connection:

```
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("IN_bean_type", new MyBean());
simpleJdbcCallOperations.execute(values);
```

MyBean:

```
class MyBean implements SQLData {
    ...
    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        ...
        Clob clob = ((OracleSQLOutput)stream).getSTRUCT().getJavaSqlConnection().createClob(); //hack to get the current connection
        clob.setString(1, "stringValue");
        stream.writeClob(clob);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me here facing the same problem, but only when trying to do this with StoredProcedure

but this way

```
        conn = datsource.getConnection();
        cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call schema.package.function(?)}");
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.CLOB);
        cstmt.setClob(2, clob);
        cstmt.execute();
```

works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. And you can correct it. I make my contribution, hoping it can serve you.

```
public PreparedStatement insertaReprocesos(TimerLog timer, List<ReprocesosDTO> listaInsertaProcesos) throws SQLException, Exception{
    Connection conexion = null;
    CallableStatement cstmt = null;
    String query = null;
    try {
        conexion = JDBCUtils.getConnection(UtilProperties.DATASOURCE);
        Connection conexion2 = JDBCUtils.getImplementsConnectionAllServer(conexion);
        query= UtilProperties.SP_INSERTA_REPROCESOS;
        cstmt = conexion.prepareCall(query);
        Object[] recordArray = new Object[6];
        Struct[] structs = new Struct[listaInsertaProcesos.size()];
        int registroCont = 0;
        Clob myClob = conexion2.createClob();
        for(ReprocesosDTO registro : listaInsertaProcesos) {
            Reader reader = registro.getFcregistro().getCharacterStream();//esta variable la esta declarada como Clob
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            myClob.setString(1, br.readLine());
            
                recordArray[0] = registro.getFiprocesoId();
                recordArray[1] = registro.getFdfecha();
                recordArray[2] = (registro.getFisecuencia());
                recordArray[3] = registro.getFistatusid();
                recordArray[4] = myClob;// este dato en BD esta declarado como CLOB
                recordArray[5] = registro.getFcusuario();
                structs[registroCont++] = conexion2.createStruct(UtilProperties.TYP_REPORTE_PROCESOS, recordArray);
        }
        Array oracleRecord = ((OracleConnection) conexion2).createOracleArray(UtilProperties.TYPE_TAREPORTE,structs);
        cstmt.setArray(1, oracleRecord);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(MonitorConstants.PA_CODIGO_SALIDA_2,OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(MonitorConstants.PA_MENSAJE_SALIDA_3,OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        
        cstmt.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Mensaje "+e.getMessage()+"Causa: "+e.getCause());
        timer.setTiempoParcial(MonitorConstants.MONITOR_DAO, MonitorConstants.INSERTA_PROCESOS);
        throw new SQLException(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        timer.setTiempoParcial(MonitorConstants.MONITOR_DAO, MonitorConstants.INSERTA_PROCESOS);
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
    return cstmt;
}
```

Comment: Please ask your question in English.