# ORA-22922 while passing blob to oracle procedure from kotlin app

Tags: java, oracle, kotlin, stored-procedures

Code creating BLOB and passing it to procedure:

```
override fun saveImage(pdByteArray: ByteArray?, imageFormat: String): Long {
    val blob = dataSource.connection.createBlob()
    blob.setBytes(1, pdByteArray)

    val parameters = hashMapOf(
            "p_image_data" to blob,
            "p_image_format" to imageFormat
    )

    val out = saveImageFileCall.execute(parameters)
    return ((out["p_file_id"] ?: 0) as BigDecimal).toLong()
}
```

Oracle procedure:

```
  PROCEDURE save_image(p_file_id          OUT    VARCHAR2,
                       p_image_data       IN     BLOB,
                       p_image_format     IN     VARCHAR2)
  IS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO images (image_id, image_data, image_format)
    VALUES (images_seq.nextval, p_image_data, p_image_format)
    RETURNING image_id INTO p_file_id;
  END;
```

Result is ORA-22922. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419567/simplejdbccall-calling-pl-sql-procedure-ora-22922-nonexistent-lob-value

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279571/spring-send-blob-to-stored-procedure) was helpful

There is no need to create BLOB, you can pass simple byte array to procedure - but you have to bind that array with OracleTypes.BINARY:

```
saveImageFileCall = SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                    .withSchemaName(dataSource.connection.schema)
                    .withCatalogName("images_pkg")
                    .withProcedureName("save_image")
                    .declareParameters(
                            SqlParameter("p_image_data", OracleTypes.BINARY),
                            SqlParameter("p_image_format", OracleTypes.NVARCHAR)
                    )
...
  val parameters = hashMapOf(
                "p_image_data" to pdByteArray,
                "p_image_format" to imageFormat
        )

  val out = saveImageFileCall.execute(parameters)
```